# how to set up correctly belongsTo relation on looback 3?

Tags: node.js, relationship, loopbackjs, strongloop

i have a trouble with belongsTo relation on loopback 3, 
it's a one to one relation, one clientParticipation have one kartParticipation
here is my configuration for each model

```
KartParticipation.json

"ClientParticipation": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "ClientParticipation",
      "foreignKey": "kartParticipationId"
    },
```

```
ClientParticipation.json

"KartParticipation": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "KartParticipation",
      "foreignKey": "clientParticipationId"
    },
```

when i try to save my relation like

```
kartParticipation.ClientParticipation(clientParticipation);
```

i can see with

```
console.log(clientParticipation)
```

that my relation are correctly done but not stored in database

can someone explain me what i doing wrong please ?

Comment: Are you sure the database config is correctly set?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure about it table clientParticipation have kartParticipationId and table kartParticipation have clientParticipationId Key, the problem is probably on my relation configuration or my understanding of loopback relation

Comment: After you call `.clientParticipantion(...)`, do you save the kartParticipation model? Maybe it's required`kartParticipation.save() // <-- do you call it?`

Comment: Thanks you @akkonrad , I was thinking that kartParticipation.ClientParticipation(clientParticipation); had automatically save the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am wrong, but two relations *belongsTo* mean nothing to me...
This is what I would do instead:

In `KartParticipation.json`:

```
"clientParticipation": {  //starts the included relation with a lowerCase might be best practice, tho
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "ClientParticipation",
      "foreignKey": "" //you don't need to precise a custom foreign if you use the classic one (easiest to read, imo)
    }
```

In `ClientParticipation.json`:

```
"kartParticipation": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "KartParticipation",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
```

Then, to add a relation:

```
ClientParticipation.findOne({where: {id: 'your_id'}}, function (err, clientParticipation) {
                if (err)
                    return cb(err, null);

                if (clientParticipation && clientParticipation.id) {
                    var newKartParticipation = {'object_with': 'your_datas'};
                    clientParticipation.kartParticipation.add(newKartParticipation); // this is the code you were seeking, tho
                }
            });
```

Finally, you can check if the relation exists by requesting:

```
GET /ClientParticipation/{id}/kartParticipation
```

or programmatically:

```
ClientParticipation.findOne({where: {id: 'your_id'}, include : 'kartParticipation'}, function (err, clientParticipation) {
    console.log(clientParticipation.kartParticipation);
});
```